# Detached entity won't update property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have a simple object with a child entity attached to it. 
When I update the detached object the property with the child object isn't saved. I read a lot of posts on this form but can't figure out why it isn't updating.

See here the internal methods for updating the entity:

```
public class HtmlContent : ITextContentItem, ICreateStamp, IEditStamp, IImmutable
{
    // ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Local
    private HtmlContent()
    {

    }

    public HtmlContent(string name, string description, string text, DateTime creationDate,
        DateTime? lastEditDate, ApplicationUser createdBy, ApplicationUser lastEditedBy)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Text = text;
        this.CreationDate = creationDate;
        this.LastEditDate = lastEditDate;
        this.CreatedBy = createdBy;
        this.LastEditedBy = lastEditedBy;
    }

    public HtmlContent(int id, string name, string description, string text, DateTime creationDate,
        DateTime? lastEditDate, ApplicationUser createdBy, ApplicationUser lastEditedBy)
        : this(name, description, text, creationDate, lastEditDate, createdBy, lastEditedBy)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public string Description { get; private set; }

    public string Text { get; private set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; private set; }

    public DateTime? LastEditDate { get; private set; }

    public ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; private set; }

    public ApplicationUser LastEditedBy { get; private set; }

    internal HtmlContent SetLastEditInfo(DateTime? lastEditDate, ApplicationUser lastEditedBy)
    {
        if ((lastEditDate.HasValue && lastEditedBy == null) || 
            (!lastEditDate.HasValue && lastEditedBy != null))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(lastEditDate)} and {nameof(lastEditedBy)} must be used together");
        }

        return new HtmlContent(this.Id, this.Name, this.Description, this.Text, this.CreationDate, lastEditDate, this.CreatedBy, lastEditedBy);
    }

    internal HtmlContent UpdateHtmlContent(string name, string description, string text)
    {
        return new HtmlContent(this.Id, name, description, text, this.CreationDate, this.LastEditDate, this.CreatedBy, this.LastEditedBy);
    }
}
```

See here the update method:

```
public async Task Edit(int id, string name, string description, string text)
{
    try
    {
        var content = await this.WithId(id);
        this.db.Entry(content).State = EntityState.Detached;

        var currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var lastEditedBy = this.userProvider.GetCurrentUser();

        content = content.SetLastEditInfo(currentDate, lastEditedBy);
        content = content.UpdateHtmlContent(name, description, text);

        this.db.Entry(content).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await this.db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        var errors = ex.EntityValidationErrors;
        throw;
    }
}
```

All the other properties are updated just fine. Only `LastEditedBy` isn't updated. In the Create method the `CreatedBy` is working correct because then it is a new entity saved to the database.
The `ApplicationUser` properties have foreign keys in the database generated by code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a foreign key property in the model (there was already a foreign key in the database but generated with code first). In that way, you can set the property in the constructor if there is a `LastEditedBy` user.

```
public class HtmlContent : ITextContentItem, ICreateStamp, IEditStamp, IImmutable
{
    // ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Local
    private HtmlContent()
    {

    }

    public HtmlContent(string name, string description, string text, DateTime creationDate,
        DateTime? lastEditDate, ApplicationUser createdBy, ApplicationUser lastEditedBy)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Text = text;
        this.CreationDate = creationDate;
        this.LastEditDate = lastEditDate;
        this.CreatedBy = createdBy;

        this.LastEditedBy = lastEditedBy;
        this.LastEditedById = LastEditedBy?.Id; // Set the id if it isn't null
    }

    public HtmlContent(int id, string name, string description, string text, DateTime creationDate,
        DateTime? lastEditDate, ApplicationUser createdBy, ApplicationUser lastEditedBy)
        : this(name, description, text, creationDate, lastEditDate, createdBy, lastEditedBy)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public string Description { get; private set; }

    public string Text { get; private set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; private set; }

    public DateTime? LastEditDate { get; private set; }

    public ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; private set; }

    [ForeignKey("LastEditedById")] // Set the foreign key to existing property
    public ApplicationUser LastEditedBy { get; private set; }

    // Use a property in the model for saving and not just a property generated by code first in the database
    public string LastEditedById { get; private set; }

    internal HtmlContent SetLastEditInfo(DateTime? lastEditDate, ApplicationUser lastEditedBy)
    {
        if ((lastEditDate.HasValue && lastEditedBy == null) || 
            (!lastEditDate.HasValue && lastEditedBy != null))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(lastEditDate)} and {nameof(lastEditedBy)} must be used together");
        }

        return new HtmlContent(this.Id, this.Name, this.Description, this.Text, this.CreationDate, lastEditDate, this.CreatedBy, lastEditedBy);
    }

    internal HtmlContent UpdateHtmlContent(string name, string description, string text)
    {
        return new HtmlContent(this.Id, name, description, text, this.CreationDate, this.LastEditDate, this.CreatedBy, this.LastEditedBy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I might be wrong because I have never tried to do this the way you are doing it but I can see multiple issues with your model.

**1. Your data model has private setters and does not have a parameterless constructor.**
Your data model should only be a bunch of properties that have public setters and getters and a parameterless constructor. This allows EF to proxy the navigation properties so that it 'knows' when a property has been set.

**2. Your code to populate the model is inside the model itself.**
While this is not a massive issue, it does not allow you to use something like generic repositories and such in the future. All model will have to *know* how to manipulate themselves which can lead to some unreadable code. Check out the **Repository Pattern**

**3. Having Foreign Keys defined for your navigation properties**
Again while this is not 100% important, it allows you to set related entities without having to select them from the database first. You can just set the Id of the related entity.

**4. You should not create a new entity to set its properties**
The breaks the tracking for EF, and also breaks all referential integrity of the entity. You want the entity to be the same object for its lifespan. This allows the properties to be modified without losing the object and any tracking with EF.

My suggestion is this:

```
public class HtmlContent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastEditDate { get; set; }

    public int CreatedById { get; set; }

    public int LastEditedById { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser LastEditedBy { get; set; }
}


public HtmlContentService
{
    public async Task Edit(int id, string name, string description, string text)
    {
        try
        {
            var content = await this.WithId(id);

            // no need to detach the object if you arent disposing the context
            //this.db.Entry(content).State = EntityState.Detached; 

            var currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var lastEditedBy = this.userProvider.GetCurrentUser();

            // these methods could just be moved into this method
            this.SetLastEditInfo(content, currentDate, lastEditedBy);
            this.UpdateHtmlContent(content, name, description, text);

            this.db.Entry(content).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await this.db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            var errors = ex.EntityValidationErrors;
            throw;
        }
    }

    private void SetLastEditInfo(
        HtmlContent content, 
        DateTime lastEditDate, 
        ApplicationUser lastEditedBy)
    {
        if ((lastEditDate.HasValue && lastEditedBy == null) || 
            (!lastEditDate.HasValue && lastEditedBy != null))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                $"{nameof(lastEditDate)} and {nameof(lastEditedBy)} must be used together");
        }

        content.LastEditDate = lastEditDate;
        content.LastEditedBy = lastEditedBy;
    }

    private void UpdateHtmlContent(
        HtmlContent content, 
        string name, 
        string description, 
        string text)
    {
        content.Name = name;
        content.Description = description;
        content.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd put my bet on reason #4.

Comment: First, thank you for the reaction. I updated the question with almost the complete model. I removed al not necessary information like attributes. I have a constructor which is `private`. I created the properties for a reason with private set because then you can't set the values from outside of the object. The object must have al the logic on how it is maintained and not some other surface. Because if you can change it in one class, you can change it in multiple. After that, code duplication is around the corner. I also said that my entity was detached. That is because I don't want tracking.

Comment: I add an answer with the solution for the problem. Now the object is `immutable` outside the object itself. Thank you for pointing me out in the right direction.